# What is recommended for cassandra max connections per host? How is it calculated?

Tags: cassandra

Is there a way to limit number of connections per host in cassandra cluster and based on what parameter this is calculated?

In some of cassandra node i can see established connections count for 9042 goes up to 1400+, is this something i need to worry about?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can limit the number of connections per host in the Cassandra cluster.

If you are using the C++ driver, check [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/2.7/api/struct.CassCluster/) out.

I visualize any query following the below path:

```
Client --> Session --> IO threads --> Connections --> Nodes
```

You can configure the number of IO threads(This is the number of threads that will handle query requests) associated with the session. In each IO thread, you can then configure the number of connections per host. If needed, the number of connections per host will increase based on certain parameters(The maximum count up to which this can be increased is also configurable).

So, at max, there can be x number of connections per host where,

> x = **number_of_sessions** * **number_of_IO_threads** * **max_number_of_connections_per_host**

All 3 variables on RHS in the above equation are configurable.

Also check out:

- https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28219086/5701173